# Ошибка kivy: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, kivy

Когда пытаюсь запустить код с kivy вылезает ошибка SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

код это пример с сайта kivy

```
 from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Button(text="Hello world")

TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Это весь код?  Какой полный текст ошибки?

Answer (score 1):

В строке `from kivy.uix.button import button`, `Button` нужно с большой буквы.

```
from kivy.uix.button import Button
```

Хотя странно ошибка звучит, может быть дело в другом.

Comment: ваш вариант не помог

Comment: код рабочий. у меня работает. Видимо дело в другом.

Comment: Спасибо что попробывали мне помочь

Comment: А где запускаете? Если в командной строке, то проблема в том, что там выполняется одна команда за раз.  вот тут можно почитать https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21226808/syntaxerror-multiple-statements-found-while-compiling-a-single-statement